# Можно ли в python при обнаружении ошибки(программа не завершается) выполнить некий код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-ошибок

Можно ли в python при обнаружении ошибки(программа не завершается)  выполнить некий код?
Вроде:

```
if Oshibca==True:
 код
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду исключение (например, деление на ноль, неправильный индекс списка и т.д.), можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```py
try:
  a = 2/0 # код, в котором ищем ошибку
except Exception: # <маркер>
  print('Ошибка =(') # что делать, если есть ошибка
```

Также, если вам нужно что-то делать при какой-то конкретной ошибке (например, только при делении на ноль), вы можете в консоли скопировать название этой ошибки и вписать его в строке с `<маркер>` вместо Exception
Пример:

```py
try:
  a = 2/0 # где ищем ошибки
except ZeroDivisionError:
  print('На ноль не дели, а то худо будет!') # что делать, если возникла ошибка деления на ноль
```